# Mongodb Lookup query on collections with ObjectId as local and foreign fields?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have two collections on which i have to do **lookup query on ObjectId of both collections**. Both local and foreign fields are of type ObjectId.
I can convert one collection ObjectId to string with $toString method but how will i do the same with the other collection i want to join?

Json 1:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "4efcggedwrg446"
    },
    "name": "Name1",
    "phone": "12345678"
}
```

Json 2:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "4efcggedwrg446"
  },
  "deviceId": "6552gggh732",
  "deviceName": "samsung"
}
```

Query:

```
[{$addFields: {
  "Id": { "$toString": "$_id" }
}}, {$lookup: {
  from: 'json2',
  localField: 'Id',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'join'
}}]
```

Lookup query on **_id** of both json. How can i convert ObjectId of other collection ?

Comment: why do you need to convert it to string?

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya Is there any way i can do lookup operation of ObjectId ? then i don't need to convert it to string

Comment: yes you can do but your question seems odd, can you clarify your data you have provided

Comment: I have two collections which are linked via ObjectId i.e "_id" . I need to join them via lookup to get device of each user.

Comment: what is `$oid` ? its not ObjectId

Comment: yes it is ObjectId

Comment: @RahulAnand : if both fields of same type why do you need to convert again ? Just refer both fields as is (you can compare on `ObjectId()'s`)!! Are you having any issue with that ?

Comment: @srinivasy Yes, i am getting empty array on joins when in my data each user has a device and i am doing lookup on user collection with device collection.

Comment: @RahulAnand : Do you mean to say `join :[]` ? Can you remove that `$addFields` & refer `_id` in both local & foreign fields & let me know.. Also do you really have same `_ids` for both collections ??

Comment: yes, this is working. Some Id's were missing randomly, that's where i got confused

Comment: @RahulAnand : So is your query working or still having issues - if yes please edit question with particular issue? If your query is working fine then please close this question as it's just an user input issue rather it doesn't have any issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Collection1**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33bfc008591b180967753a"),
    "name" : "Name1",
    "phone" : "12345678"
}
```

**Collection2**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33bfe508591b180967753b"),
    "iUserId" : ObjectId("5e33bfc008591b180967753a"),
    "deviceId" : "6552gggh732",
    "deviceName" : "samsung"
},
```

To join both with `lookup`

```
const query = [
    {
        $lookup:
            {
                from: "Collection2",
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "iUserId",
                as: "User"
            }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$User"
    }
];

db.Collection1.aggregate(query)
```

**Result:-**
You can apply `$project` to get specific fields

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33bfc008591b180967753a"),
    "name" : "Name1",
    "phone" : "12345678",
    "User" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e33bfe508591b180967753b"),
        "iUserId" : ObjectId("5e33bfc008591b180967753a"),
        "deviceId" : "6552gggh732",
        "deviceName" : "samsung"
    }
}
```